# Someone can explain the code?

Tags: c, pointers

I have to assign to the variable "j" value of the variable "i" using only a pointer to char. I couldn't write code, so I see this solution but I don't understand what happen in the "for" body. Can someone explain it to me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int i = 10;   
int j = 20;  
char *p, *q;  

p = (char*)&i;   
q = (char*)&j;

for(int k = 0; k < sizeof(i); ++k) {  
    *(q + k) = *(p + k);    
}

printf("%d == %d\n", i, j); 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*(q + k)` is the same as `q[k]`. Go from there.

Comment: Pointer to char will point to separate bytes of the integer. Your loop runs  `sizeof(i)` number of times, which represents the number of bytes that `integer i` takes on your machine. Now combine this with the @dhke 's comment

Comment: Not sure your question is well made with this title. For the answer, the instruction in the for affect the value at (p + k) address into the bloc at (q + k) address.

Comment: `p = (char*)&i;` is aliasing an `int*` as `char*` pointer. `sizeof(i)` is the number of bytes required by `int` which is used as the length of a `char` array.

Comment: Of topic: An alternative solution would be to replace the `for` loop with jus `memcpy(q, p, sizeof i);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to these statements

```
p = (char*)&i;   
q = (char*)&j;
```

objects `i` and `j` are considered (interpreted) like character arrays that have `sizeof( int )` characters. And in this loop

```
for(int k = 0; k < sizeof(i); ++k) {  
    *(q + k) = *(p + k);    
}
```

these characters are copied from the integer variable `i` to the integer variable `j` byte by byte.

As for these expressions  `*(q + k)` and `*(p + k)` the  they are fully equivalent to `q[k]` and `p[k]`. Thus the loop can be rewritten using this syntax

```
for(int k = 0; k < sizeof(i); ++k) {  
    q[k] = p[k];    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. no difference in using `++k` instead of `k++`?

Comment: @GianniCaringi If to use them as a stand-alone expressions then there is no difference for fundamental types.

Answer (score 0):

```
p = (char*)&i;   
q = (char*)&j;
```

Now p and q pointing to lowest byte of i and j because char pointer can point to only one byte. In for loop, Incrementation of pointers makes pointers to point to next byte and simultaneously byte is copied into memory pointed by q.

Answer (score 0):

The code does precisely what you were looking for, copies the value of j to variable i. But it does it byte by byte.

```
p = (char*)&i;   
q = (char*)&j;
```

This initializes the value of p and q as the pointers to the first byte of i and j respectively.

```
sizeof(i);
```

this returns the size of the variable j in terms of number of bytes (4 in this case).

Then in the for loop:

```
for(int k = 0; k < sizeof(i); ++k) {  
    *(q + k) = *(p + k);    
}
```

We go to

```
*(q + k)
```

This points to the memory address of [(start address of j) + k]th byte.
Same applies for variable i ->

```
*(p+k)
```

Thus then each value at the (p+k)th memory location gets copied into the address pointed by (q+k)th address.

Hence we have j==i.